Print 2 external PDF files while working on excel sheet
While working on excel worksheet, I need to print 2 different external PDF files in the same folder for my clients to sign.
Here are the files paths "D:\Templates to Print\Acknowledgment.pdf" and "D:\Templates to Print\Works Permit.pdf"
I have found this code while searching through internet but unfortunately not working
sub print_file()

Print_and_Close_PDF "D:\Templates to Print\Acknowledgment.pdf"
End sub`



To clarify, you're asking to open already existing PDF files using VBA and print them to a connected printer?

As an alternative;
Sub Test()
    Dim file1 As String, file2 As String
    
    file1 = "D:\Templates to Print\Acknowledgment.pdf"
    file2 = "D:\Templates to Print\Works Permit.pdf"
    
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName(file1).InvokeVerb ("Print")
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName(file2).InvokeVerb ("Print")
End Sub


Thank you so much for your help - it's very simple, fast and working perfectly

Verified works here :
Option Explicit

Sub PrintPDF()
Dim pdfPath As String
Dim pdfPath2 As String
Dim acroPath As String
Dim acroPath2 As String
' Set the path to the FIRST PDF file
pdfPath = "D:\Templates to Print\Acknowledgment.pdf"
' Set the path to Adobe Acrobat Reader (adjust if your path is different)
acroPath = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
' Print the PDF file
Shell """" & acroPath & """ /t """ & pdfPath & """", vbNormalFocus
' Set the path to the SECOND PDF file
pdfPath2 = "D:\Templates to Print\Works Permit.pdf"
' Print the PDF file
Shell """" & acroPath & """ /t """ & pdfPath2 & """", vbNormalFocus
End Sub

thank you so myuch for your help - I do appreciate that

You are welcome.

Across platforms the best and easiest PDF to Printout application (Virtual as images or system physical printer) is GhostScript.
Often wrapped unnecessarily in programming languages or complex scripts!
All that is required in windows is a nominal output and a list of files to process. (If using a cmd file you may need double %'s they will be converted to one each on the command line)
"path to \GSwin##c.exe" -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -o "%printer%\\printServer\printerNameWith Spaces" @"list.txt"

Thus in excel you can export your list of files to a text file and run that.
list.txt
"D:\Templates to Print\Acknowledgment.pdf"
"D:\Templates to Print\Works Permit.pdf"

As an example here we emulate sending 2 single page PDFs to the printer and can see there are 2 pages flowing through the print queue.


thank you so much for yuor effort to help me
